# Outputting simple integer value in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Having such simple output printing code:

```
swprintf_s(g_msgbuf, L"--> val: %llu<--\n", 0xfffffff);
OutputDebugString(g_msgbuf);
    
swprintf_s(g_msgbuf, L"--> val: %llu<--\n", 0x100000000);
OutputDebugString(g_msgbuf);
```

I'm getting following warning:

> Size mismatch: 'int' passed as *Param*(3) when 'long long' is required
> in call to 'swprintf_s'.

regarding the first `swprintf_s` function call(the second `swprintf_s` call is ok - no warning and outputs `4 294 967 294` as expected). Moreover the value outputted is: `34359214650425343` while it should of course be: `4 294 967 295`

What's wrong with the first `swprintf_s` function call? Why is the warning and why the output isn't just as expected(`4 294 967 295`)?

Comment: Because `0xfffffff` is a [literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) of type `int`. But `%llu` expects an `unsigned long long`. So, you can use `0xffffffffULL` instead.

Comment: 34359214650425343d is 007A11860FFFFFFFh. you will recognize your number, preceded by garbage.

Comment: The weird value is getting printed because the stack gets corrupted: `swprintf_s` sees the format specifier `%llu` and pops 8 bytes, but you pushed only a 4-byte integer.

Comment: Ok, but since int is WIDER then unsigned long WHY doesn't the compiler do some auto conversion and if the target type is wider than passed just precedes the passed vale by 00000000h to get the correct value?

Comment: @darro911 `int` is narrower than `unsigned long long` and `swprintf_s` is a C-style variadic function which aren't type-safe, nothing regarding the passed type is checked, there is no target type to convert to. That's why you should avoid using them whenever possible in C++.

Comment: Use `std::format` if you have C++20 available. It is a proper typesafe C++ API.